# Copy to clipboard is worked fine on PC but not works on Android device

Tags: javascript, android

My approach of copy to clipboard works fine on pc but has not worked on android. I tried on chrome(latest version) on my Samsung galaxy s20fe android version 12

```
<button onClick={() => handleCopy()}>Copy</button>
```

```
const clipboardData = `Name: ${modalData.name}
   Department: ${modalData.department}
   Batch: ${modalData.batch}
   BG: ${modalData.bg}
   Phone: ${modalData.phone}`;

    const handleCopy = () => {
        navigator.clipboard
            .writeText(clipboardData)
            .then(() => {
                alert('successfully copied');
            })
            .catch(() => {
                alert('something went wrong');
            });
      alert(' Coppied to clipboard!');
    };
```

Comment: which version of chrome are you using on android ? It might be problem with browser support

Comment: What is in logs of your Chrome on Android? Are you sure that text wasn't copied? Also your last alert (`alert(' Coppied to clipboard!');`) will not work as you expect. Because your Promise from `navigator.clipboard` will be not resolved yet.

Comment: True, You also need to move `alert()` inside `then` for correct behaviour as @MichaelSivolobov stated

Answer (score 2):

Accroding to [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard#clipboard_availability) documentation

> The asynchronous clipboard API is a relatively recent addition, and the process of implementing it in browsers is not yet complete. Due to both potential security concerns and technical complexities, the process of integrating this API is happening gradually in most browsers.

So you can try this:

```
    const handleCopy= () => {
        const element = document.createElement("textarea");
        element.value = clipboardData;
        document.body.appendChild(element)
        element.select();
        document.execCommand("copy");
        document.body.removeChild(element);
        alert(' Coppied to clipboard!');
    }
```